# How to click on element in Selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new in Selenium and Python. I have the following code:

```
<div class="Product_ImageWrapper__3W7pX">
        <span class=" lazy-load-image-background opacity lazy-load-image-loaded" style="color: 
         transparent; display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
            <img class="Product_Image__1sMZc" src="xxx.jpg" alt="photo" height="100%" 
             width="100%"></span></div>
```

What I'm trying to do is click on this image. There is always message:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:......

I tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[img/@src="xxx.jpg"]').click()
```

or just by the name of the class but it doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `execute()` function. It executes the code directly in the `JavaScript` Console.

```
driver.execute("document.getElementsByClassName(' lazy-load-image-background opacity lazy-load-image-loaded')[0].click()")
```

IF that did not work out, There is a second method using the `WebdriverWait()`.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(self.webdriver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class=" lazy-load-image-background opacity lazy-load-image-loaded"]')))
```

Comment: still doesn't work. The first solution throws out the error: KeyError: "document.getElementsByClassName(' lazy-load-image-background opacity lazy-load-image-loaded')[0].click()" and the second is executed, but the element doen't get clicked.

Comment: @TigerJ I have forgotten to add `click()` in the second one. Try that `WebDriverWait(self.webdriver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class=" lazy-load-image-background opacity lazy-load-image-loaded"]'))).click()`

Comment: After clicking on the picture, a small window should pop up.  This time I see that it finds an element (there is no error), but the window after clicking doesn't show up.

Comment: @TigerJ so try to click another element - I mean I tried to click span, so try to use `'img[class="Product_Image__1sMZc"]'`.

Comment: 'img[class="Product_Image__1sMZc"] it works for me. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Please use following xpath "**//img[@src='xxx.jpg']**

Before to click you should wait for that element

Comment: Still get this message: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element . And yes, I wait a few seconds each time for an element to show up.

Comment: Just got the solution.

Comment: if my answer usefull to you upvote answer so that others can get idea